# "pages" useless backref in the end of bibliography section compiled with pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)

Tags: bibliographies, errors, back-referencing

Got an odd misprint at end of thebibliography enviroment, how to get rid of it and don't get an error with too many citations. Having only five of them I got an error of compilation "File ended while scanning use of \BR@@bibitem.". But

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{backref}

\title{Translated by the machine}



\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
\bibitem{notes} Gschwind M. K. {\em Method and apparatus for determining branch addresses in programs generated by binary translation } 1998.
\bibitem{notes} Michael Matz, Jan Hubicka, Andreas Jaeger, Mark Mitchell {\em System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement} 2013.
\end{thebibliography}\par

\end{document}
```

MiKTeX compiles in
[image: Example of misprint]

where shouldn't be any "pages" for every citation as I don't define them.

Log for listfiles is
"Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded."

Comment: Thanks and no need for sorry. But you made your code less minimal (we do not need title,`tikz`, Russian text a.s.o.) without showing the problem. If I compile it right now, I see one line of bib which looks good. No "pages" around.

Comment: How is `miktex` relevant in this case? (Just to mention that the title and some of the wording here is not relevant to the issue)

Comment: It is more important that you post a list of the package versions you have used. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, then a version list is printed in the log. Please copy it and post it as a part of your question. BTW: Your example compiles just fine, with no extra `pages` stuff using TeX Live 2015

Comment: Your example is not a correct example. It doesn't show the behaviour you describe, it also can't give your error as `\BR@@bibitem` is a command from the backref package which the example doesn't load. Inventing examples is **bad**. It waste the time of the people willing to help you. Beside this: Make sure that there is an empty line after every bib entry. And use distinct keys in the `\bibitem`. Don't use `{notes}` for every one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I appreciate your help for a newbe co-forumer, I've done everything your asked. While trying to make it minimal, really faced the problem only with backref package. But I need it for referral Table of contents refs, could I disable it before the bibliography or should I use .bib file?

Comment: As I wrote: Add empty lines after every bibitem. Read the documentation of backref to understand why (and what the package is doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the backref description, it does nothing but as a part of hyperref package:
"Make hyper-references back from bibliography to citation."

And iff you want to really reffer to pages in your work, you should use it.
Just delete the use of this package and odd "pages" would go away or just study how to use packages you include.

Thanks @UlrikeFischer for guidance, sometimes people just need some mentorship while doing their thesis.